# Deleted my stock phone application from android phone after rooting as a result can't call for now

Tags: root-access

I recently rooted my HTC desire 728 and by mistake deleted the stock phone app and as a result, now I can't make calls ... the phone is not showing any sim signals too and when I go to sim settings it shows  process.com.android.phone stopped  ... what can I do now? I had factory reset the phone already a couple of times but the after root deleted apps are not showing up ... please help me out

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have taken no backup, which implies that you have to flash the stock firmware. Since you have rooted your phone, I believe you already have a custom recovery like TWRP installed (if not, go ahead and flash one. Search google for the exact instructions for your phone). Then search Google for the stock firmware, and you should be able to find a version of the stock ROM. Download and move this to the phone storage, and flash it with the custom recovery. You might have to clear all internal storage data and/or Dalvik cache and system partitions before/after the flash. Check Google and XDA Developers for the exact instructions.

Note that this will delete all the data of your internal storage, so make sure to take a backup before proceeding. You will lose root access as well, and the custom recovery might be overwritten with the stock recovery.